# Google Cloud Storage - Editing VPN Tunnel on Hybrid Connectivity

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ip, vpn, google-cloud-vpn

On GCP Hybrid Connectivity I eventually have the need to edit the VPN tunnels specially regarding Advertised IP ranges and Local subnetworks. Is it possible to change the tunnel configuration when such a necessity arises? So far I haven't being able to do it, requiring to recreate the tunnel which is undesired...

Comment: What type of routing? Are you using BGP? If not, why not?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to edit these VPN tunnels, you will have to delete and create new ones with the advertised IP ranges you desire "Cloud VPN disallows editing any traffic selectors after you have created a VPN. To change either the local or the remote traffic selector for a Cloud VPN tunnel, you must delete the tunnel then re-create it. You do not have to delete the Cloud VPN gateway, though." You can take a look to [this](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/choosing-networks-routing#dynamic-routing) document for more references as a workarownd by using Dynamic BGP.